# How do we describe the 'commutativity' of two different operators/operations?

Tags: commutative-algebra, operator-theory, transpose

For example the defintion of a conjugate transpose/Hermitian transpose of a matrix. I can either take it's conjugate and then transpose it or the other way.

${\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {A}}^{\dagger }}={\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {A}}^{\mathrm {H} }=\left({\overline {\boldsymbol {A}}}\right)^{\mathsf {T}}={\overline {{\boldsymbol {A}}^{\mathsf {T}}}}}$

[Wikipedia: Conjugate_transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose)

Comment: What is exactly your question? Yes, the functions $f:A\mapsto A^T$ and $g:A\mapsto \overline A$ commute: $f\circ g=g\circ f$.

Comment: uhm, my question would be if there is a different term for the commutativity of two distinct operations but if you make them into functions then i can understand how you describe it with commutativity.

Comment: An 'operation' is just synonym for 'function'. It inputs a something (now a matrix) and outputs something (now a matrix), depending only on the input.

Comment: Ahh, i think i realized the stem of my confusion. So some operations like multiplication(of two scalars) are binary but others are unary (like getting the conjugate or transpose) so i thought the commutativity stands for 'the exchangability of the inputs while getting the same answer'. So for example the equality of mixed partial second derivates is commutative too. How liberally can i use the term?

Comment: In a (semi)group, we say two elements *commute* or *are commutable* if $ab=ba$, and the binary operation is called *commutative* if all pairs commute. We have here the (semi)group of matrix operators, and those two operators *commute*.

Comment: Ahh, okay thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(B):=B^H, g(B):=\overline{B}$ and $h(B):= B^T.$

Then

$$f(A)=h(g(A))=g(h(A)).$$

Hence

$$f=h \circ g = g \circ h.$$

Comment: Ohhh! So you defined it as a function thus i can describe the commutativity of the composition?
So instead of trying to focus on the different operators, rather make it into an operation and trying to generalize it?